# Как правильно обновить ветку?

Tags: git

Нужно скачать обновленную ветку `master` с удаленного репозитория и далее все изменения из этой ветке применить в своей, чтобы моя ветка стала такой же, как `master`. Как это правильно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Команда git pull используется для извлечения и загрузки содержимого из удаленного репозитория и немедленного обновления локального репозитория этим содержимым.
Команда git pull на самом деле представляет собой комбинацию двух других команд: git fetch и git merge. На первом этапе git pull выполняется команда git fetch, ограниченная локальной веткой, на которую указывает HEAD.
Сразу после загрузки содержимого команда git pull выполняет слияние. Для слитого содержимого создается новый коммит, а указатель HEAD обновляется и начинает указывать на этот новый коммит.

Comment: В принципе, @SergeySamusik правильно написал, но не до конца. Предложенным способом Вы обновите локальный `master`, а дальше объединяете изменения мастера со  своими с помощью `merge`. Если же Вам нужно сделать локальную ветку точной копией мастера, отбросив все, что в ней  было сделано, то, как по мне, проще пересоздать ветку от нового состояния мастера.

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов, а `pull`, разве, не делает `merge`?

Comment: @nup `pull` делает мерж, но между локальной и удаленной копией одной ветки (например `origin/master` и `master`). А у ТС, как понимаю, есть мастер-ветка (`master`), и есть своя ветка (например, `branch-1`) , и ему нужно перенести изменения из удаленного мастера не в его локальную копию (`origin/master` -> `master`), а в свою ветку (`origin/master` -> `branch-1`).